# Datagrid to csv not saving to file

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

A button in my app is meant to take the data from a datagrid and write it to a csv file , no error is being thrown and the file is being created however it is empty , any ideas how to solve this ?? using vs2012

```
    private void btnExportShareClass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        string strString = str.ToString();
        string Filepath = txtSaveShareClass.Text.ToString();

        foreach (DataRow dr in this.CalcDataSet.Client)
        {
            foreach (object field in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                str.Append(field.ToString() + ",");
            }
            str.Replace(",", "\n", str.Length - 1, 1);
        }

        try
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Filepath, strString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Write Error" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're writing strString to the file which is actually empty? Have you tried str.ToString() instead?

i.e.  `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Filepath, str.ToString());`